# Converting a column of lists to its length

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column consisting of lists. I wish to mutate to create a new value for each row containing the length of each of these lists, but I'm having trouble doing that

I've tried

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=I(list(1,1:2,1:3)))

df %>%  mutate(len = length(b))
```

but this just sets len to the the number of rows in the dataframe (value of len is 3 for every row). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @AdamQuek I've provided a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, use

```
df %>%  mutate(len = lengths(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do `unnest` and create the new column

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   unnest %>%
   group_by(a) %>% 
   mutate(c = n())
```